# A sum of consecutive numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

one more time i need help of community. There is this code. I underrstand pretty everything but not the ending. I am counting on you. So we have a function where we add an indicated elements to each other

```
  function array_max_consecutive_sum(nums, k) {
    let result = 0;
    let temp_sum = 0;
    // veriable where we collects results
    for (var i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        // first loop where we go through elements but it is limited to value of k
        // result
        temp_sum += nums[i];
        for (var i = k - 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            // the second loop but this time we start from position where we had finished
            temp_sum += nums[i];
        }
        // condiition statement which overwrites
        if (temp_sum > result) {
            result = temp_sum;
        }
        // How should i analyze this line of code. Could you simplify it for me? We have a veriable, from which we will remove, what to be specific? Another question is why we have to use "1" in this operation? 
        temp_sum -= nums[i - k + 1];
    }
    return result;
  }
        
  console.log(array_max_consecutive_sum([1, 2, 3, 14, 5], 3))
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry for the mess.

Comment: temp_sum -= nums[i - k + 1]; This line. Could you explain it to me in details? What do we remove and why we use "1" in this operation

Comment: As you want maximum k consecutive sum so you have to remove the previous element after adding k elements. This solution is not efficient, you can solve this problem more easily and efficiently with less code.

Comment: You seem to have nested `for` loops with the same loop variable `i`. This is at least unusual if not problematic, as you will be changing the outer loop's `i` while working with the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced there aren't bugs in that code.  The inner loop needs to only be executed once.  temp_sum needs to be incremented with nums[i] and decremented with nums[i-k+1] before evaluating if `(temp_sum > result)`.

This line:

```
temp_sum -= nums[i - k + 1];
```

Is apparently decrementing the running summation by excluding the last element of the previously evaluated subset.  But it needs to be doing this before the `if (temp_sum > result)` statement.

I rewrote the implementation to something that I think is cleaner, faster, and more correct.

```
function array_max_consecutive_sum(nums, k) {

    if ((nums.length < k) || (k <= 0)) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    let result = 0;
    let temp_sum = 0;

    // iterations is the number of sub arrays of length k to evalaute
    let iterations = nums.length - k + 1;

    // do first iteration where we sum up nums[0] up to and including nums[k-1]
    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        temp_sum += nums[i];
    }
    result = temp_sum;

    let start = 0;
    iterations--; // we just completed the first iteration

    // now evaluate each subset by subtracting the first item
    // from the left and adding in a new item onto the right
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        temp_sum -= nums[start];    // remove the first element of the previous set
        temp_sum += nums[start+k];  // add the last element of the new set
        start++;

        // evaluate this subset sum
        if (temp_sum > result) {
            result = temp_sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice. You are great community :) I will analyze everything what have you sent. Good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another short solution (*not* a one-liner!) that should also do the job. I now understand what the parameter `k` was supposed to do and worked it into my solution too.

I now reverse the array in order to avoid having to do any housekeeping on intermediate lists (for those cases where more than `k` consecutive numbers were encountered).

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 10, 1];

function maxListSum(arr,k){
 let j=0;
 return Math.max(...arr.reverse().reduce((l, c, i, a) => {
    if (i && c == a[i - 1] - 1 && i-j<k){ // as of second element: if it is a consecutive number: 
      l[l.length - 1] += c      // add to current sum in l[l.length-1]
    } else {l.push(c);j=i;}     // otherwise: start a new sum in l
    return l
  }, []))
}

console.log(maxListSum(arr,3))
```

The `Array.prototype.reduce()` function call accumulates the sums of consecutive number sequences into an array which is then spread out as arguments for the outer `Math.max()`-call to find and return the highest of the collected sums.

**Update** ( hopefully the last one :D )
Following @BenStephen's helpful comment, here is a short script that will calculate the largest sum of k consecutive numbers in an array (the numbers do *not* need to form a "sequence" of any kind).

```js
function largestSumOfKNums(arr,k){
 for (var s,i=0,sum=0;i<=arr.length-k;i++){
  s = arr.slice(i,i+k).reduce((a,c)=>a+c);
  if (s>sum) sum=s;
 }
 return sum
}

console.log(largestSumOfKNums([20,30,-100,4,3],2))
```

Comment: Why do you call this a "one-liner"? It has a statement block with two `if` statements and a `return` statement...

Comment: Yep - right - I overlooked that. So: it is _not_ a one-liner!  :-)

Comment: You aren't taking the `k` parameter into consideration.  Or are you?

Comment: @selbie: Now "the penny dropped" with me! :D No, I did not yet use the `k` parameter in my answer and, yes, I will look at how to include it now! ;-)

Comment: Ok, the parameter `k` (the maximum number of consecutive elements for a sum) has also been included in my solution.

Comment: Invoking `maxListSum([20,30,-100,4,3],2)` with your code returns `30`. I would assert it should return `7`.

Comment: OK, but what does OP want? Do the lists of consecutive numbers have to be longer than 1?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann @selbie In the original code there's no part that checks whether the next number is the current number + 1 to determine if it's 'consecutive'. So maybe consecutive here just means 'next in the array'? In which case `maxListSum([20,30,-100,4,3],2)` should be 50 (which is what @selbie's code produces).

Comment: @BenStephens - Thanks, that solves this riddle! :D Well, it has been an interesting little puzzle nonetheless! :D